# Changing location of referenced project in VS solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, projects-and-solutions, solution

I use Team Foundation Server for source control. All of my projects use a structure that have dev, main, and release branches.

For the purposes of this question, I have 2 TFS projects, one is my application and the other is a shared library. The solution file for my application includes the shared library project (even though it is in a separate TFS project) because it makes it easier to debug. So I have a solution in 1 TFS project pointing to a project in another one.

The problem I'm running into relates to branches. What I'd like to do is point to the dev branch version of the shared library when in the dev branch of my application's solution. Similarly I want the main branch version of my solution to point to the shared library in the main branch, etc.

Does anyone have ideas of how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if this is the best way, but I'm pretty sure it will work if you don't come up with anything better.

- Create a symbolic link between the two directories, and map the project using that.
- Add a pre-event MSBuild script to delete and recreate the symbolic link for each build based on the current branch.  For example:

  ```
  rmdir MyProject

  mklink /d MyProject c:\dev\Main\MyProject
  ```

You'll probably want to put this in a batch file and call that.

Comment: Thanks for the creative solution. I started playing with this, and I think it is going to hit issues because TFS maps projects to their folders on the file system. So when I used a symbolic link instead of a path, TFS gets confused and unbinds the project from source control. Even if I rebound it to the symbolic link instead of the actual path, that would mean it would map changes to all branches to that one folder which could get ugly. I'll probably give this a good try anyways to see if I can get it to work, I just want to see if any easier solutions come through first...